# How Solr Persist indexed data between restarts

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am new to Solr and have few questions related SOlr/lucene

1) how solr persist indexed data between restart  and

2) How data is shared in clustered env

Answer (score 4):

Solr maintains the [index data in files](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/fileformats.html) which is stored on the [data directory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#dataDir_parameter) mentioned in the configuration files.
The data is persisted whenever you perform a Commit on solr.
When Solr is restarted it reloads the files to get back the index.

For replicating data, you would need to you Solr replication to have the same copy of data over multiple servers.
You can also check upon [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) for Solr's distributed capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question, Solr index is stored in your local directory in a path specified in the Solr Config as in :

```
 <dataDir>/var/data/solr</dataDir>
```

Restarts load indexing information from this location.

Reference

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml